# Youtube Embed and CSS Animation Results in Dropped Frames

Tags: css, video, youtube, css-animations

I'm having an issue with pages of my site I'd like to embed YouTube videos into. After initially adding in the embeds, I noticed that they played at reduced FPS. At first I suspected YouTube's video conversion process was to blame, but the same videos seemed to play at full framerate when viewed directly on the YouTube site. In Firefox the embedded 30 FPS video would play ~20 FPS, and in Chrome only ~10 FPS, IE seems unaffected but it's also not rendering most of the CSS animations (oddly it also seems to render the 30 FPS video at 60 FPS, not clear where the extra frames come from).

Post some further poking I realized the effect was related to the use of CSS animations. If I disable the CSS animations on the page, videos play normally, but with them enabled I get the significantly reduced framerates. I'm guessing it's related to browsers keeping rendering on limited threads (although, though I thought Chrome handled that differently, it seemed to be the most effected).

Does anyone have suggestions related to this, or am I stuck picking between CSS animations and video embeds?

Comment: Make sure it uses the same player in all cases (probably flash?). Maybe this change in performance is caused by the HTML5 player kicking in...

Comment: Flashplayer (v12 on my current install) is used in both Firefox and Chrome.

Comment: Forcing video to use the HTML5 player (i.e. with parameter html5=1) seems to correct the framerate issue. It also corrects Firefox failing to respect the wmode="opaque" parameter, layering the video over all other content regardless of z-index.  
  
Unfortunately, visitors will need to have opted into the HTML5 player via [youtube.com/html5](http://youtube.com/html5) for the html5 parameter to have any effect. So using HTML5 fixes the issue, but there doesn't seem to be any way to force HTML5 use without user action. If someone can suggest a way to do so this could be closed out.